# How do I implement MySQL insert from select where column is not null

Tags: mysql

```
insert into payments2 (`ID`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`, `Committee_member`, `TotalPay`) 
select 1, '" + dateBegin + "','" + dateEnd + "',`Committee_member`,sum(Payment) 
from (
    select * 
    from sitting_registry 
    WHERE Committee_member='" + memberName + "' and Date>='" + dateBegin + "' 
        and Date<='" + dateEnd + "' 
        and committee_member IS NOT NULL 
        order by sitting_registry.Payment desc 
        limit 16
) as subt ;
```

`dateBegin`, `dateEnd`, `memberName` are variables with values from select query from which the above query is running

| ID | StartDate | EndDate | CommitteeMember | TotalPay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-01-01 | 2024-01-31 | Sam | 500 |
| 1 | 2024-01-01 | 2024-01-31 | NULL | 0 |

> ```
> sql exception:
> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'Committee_member' cannot be null
> ```

the second row with NULL will throw the SQLException, how do I skip insert where null

NOTE the query has subquery, insert into select

Comment: This is weird. Unless I'm missing something, `WHERE Committee_member=**VARNAME**` cannot return rows where `Committee_member` is `NULL`, no matter what `**VARNAME**` contains. Is it a real `NULL` or a string that spells out "NULL"·

Comment: Well, even if it's actually `'NULL'`, that doesn't explain the Java exception. Any chance the error is being thrown somewhere else?

Comment: I have eddited the query to be as is in Netbeans, the insert query is inside a while loop select query,

Comment: A `while loop select query` ....   My MySQL knowledge is not good enough for such advanced features.....    (Please share the code!)

Comment: You shouldn't even need `committee_member IS NOT NULL` because of the `Committee_member='...'` condition.

Comment: BTW, your code is open to SQL injection. You should use a prepared statement rather than concatenating variables.

Comment: You could only select the payment column in the subquery as the rest are fixed values that can be provided as literals including the column in the error message.